# Apply keyword to map vs map to keyword in Clojure

Tags: clojure

Say I have a map `{:x 1}`.

I noticed that I can lookup `:x` either by applying it to the map:

```clj
(:x {:x 1})
;=> 1
```

Or by applying the map to the keyword:

```clj
({:x 1} :x)
;=> 1
```

What's the difference between the two forms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both maps and keywords implement `IFn` and therefor can be used as functions.  The function they implement is `get`.  So it basically always translates to `(get map key default)`.

So there are rules of thumb you make up for yourself; some things to consider:

- if you have keywords in maps, using the keyword is the most common thing you will see in codebases
- if your key is not a keyword or no function (e.g. strings), you are usually better off applying the map as function (e.g. `({"a" 1} "a")`)
- whenever you are not sure if the one thing you have (the key or the map) is nil, you are better off using the thing that know for sure is not null (or else you get an exception) (e.g. `(nil {:a 1})` fails, but `({:a 1} nil)` works); if you are unsure about both: use `get`

Comment: Nice answer. Lots of good tips and useful info.